# JMeter/Blazemeter capabilities

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I am a Load Runner tester and would like to know how below requirements can be done in Jmeter.

- Data parameterization  -  How can we implement unique and random data parameterization in Jmeter.
- how do we get vuser id value for each virtual users in a Thread group?
- If we need to initialize/load any data during vuser initialization (vuser_init() in load Runner) , how can we do it? Also, how do we call any function when vuser is ending, like vusr_end() in LoadRunner.

Answer (score 1):

In Core JMeter:

- For Data parameterization, use [CSV DataSet](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) , it will pick columns from CSV file and expose them as [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions) you can use with ${varName}
- To get user id, use jmeter function [__threadNum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum)()
- There is no strict equivalent, for vuser_init you can use a [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller). For vuser_end, there is no equivalent

Answer (score -1):

1. For parameterization:

   - [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) - for sequential data
   - [Random CSV Data Set Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-the-random-csv-data-set-config-plugin-on-jmeter) - for random data
   - [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) - for unique and random data, suitable for [Distributed Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) (basically equivalent of the [Virtual Table Server](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.55/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/113800_c_paramater_overview.htm))
2. [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum)
3. Normally it is being done in:

   - `vuser_init()` - [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group)
   - `vuser_end()` - [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group)

Comment: setup Thread group does not initialize 1 VU. Setup thread group run and die before other Thread Groups